# How can I plot 3d surface plot together with 3d scatter plot in the same cube box

Tags: plotting

How can I combine them together in the same cube box

```
 Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}];

ListPointPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, 3, 0.2}, {j, 0, 3, 0.2}], 
 Filling -> Bottom]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option `DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}` to `ListPointPlot3D` and use `Show`:

```
Show[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},  
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
    MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5]], 
 ListPointPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, 3, 0.2}, {j, 0, 3, 0.2}], 
    DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}, 
    FillingStyle -> Opacity[1, Blue], 
    Filling -> Bottom]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, make your `ListPointPlot3D` input a list of `{x, y, z}` triples:

```
Show[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
    MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5]],  
 ListPointPlot3D[Join @@ Table[{i, j, Sin[j^2 + i]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.2}, {j, 0, 3, 0.2}], 
    Filling -> Bottom, 
    FillingStyle -> Opacity[1, Blue]]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Ron, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: And another question. How can I set the surface to be semi-transparent to see the points below the surface

Comment: @Ron, you can use `PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]` in `Plot3D`.